# Minimalistic visitor stats based on PHP?

Tags: php, tracking, analysis, visitor-statistic

Does anybody know a minimalistic, nice-looking visitor statistics suite based on PHP that displays visitor stats in a end-user friendly way.

I know Google Analytics, and the big names in PHP and Perl based traffic analysis; they are all too complicated and feature-rich for what I need. I am looking for something that is already totally simplified and that I don't have to strip down.

Required features:

- Visitors today, this week, this month
- Where visitors came from
- A good referer overview
- Visitors on this page
- Good filtering of bots

Optional:

- Can connect to built-in IP locator thingy, I forget the name... Anyway, I have good IP to country resolution based on one of the big providers' functions in the provider's $_SERVER variable
- A nice API and/or source code documentation to extend / interact with would be a plus.

There is no access to the server logs on the server I want to use this so the suite would have to bring its own tracking facilities, be that a PHP include, an image or a script.

Open Source would be nice, but I would consider paid solutions as well, as long as they're scripts shipped with source. I want no dependencies from external services.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps one of the most well-known PHP-based analytics applications out there is Mint (http://haveamint.com/).  It's not as feature rich as other analytics apps ... it may be too feature rich for what you are looking for.

Comment: Mint looks great. I actually had that in the back of my mind when I wrote this (but had forgotten the name and thought it was in Rails). Will look into that if no comparable Open-source solution comes a long. Cheers.

Answer (score 6):

I liked the look of [Piwiki](http://piwik.org/), however it may be a bit feature heavy for you. I is aimed at being a foss alternative to Google Analytics

Comment: +1 for Piwiki, it's not as sexy as Mint but far better (and it's free and OSS).

Comment: It's Piwik, not Piwiki.

Answer (score 4):

In most cases, you'd roll your own.  Take a look at [PHP's $_REQUEST documentation](http://us.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) and write this data into a SQL table.  You can do this portion very easily in 20 lines or less, and if you're clever - probably 5 or so.

Now, *displaying* that data can be done in any method you so choose, since you've got all the data in an SQL table.  Sort, filter, and organize using any method you please.

Comment: I've thought about that (and done it in the past) but it's not that simple. First and most important, you have to filter out bots. Then, you want to filter out recurring visitors. Then there are additional goodies that would be nice to have logged - visitor language and country for example. It tends to quickly grow beyond a handful of lines, so a ready-made solution is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics) is by far the most used of all statistic software and is the most reliable.

You get a global map of where in the world they're coming from, what specific pages they come from, duration on the site.

Comment: Just an idea, but I block google-analytics because I dislike the prevalence of Google tracking me. So if you want all of your traffic, not just those that permit GA, don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

I just started using [Clicky](http://getclicky.com/), which I am very happy with. Was using Google Analytics before, but this is a lot cleaner and clearer.

If you want to display stats to visitors you can either allow public access through the preferences, or you can use some of the [widgets](http://getclicky.com/goodies/) they provide. I would probably go with the latter.

Another cool thing is that you can actually watch real-time statistics. For example, they have a map where dots pop up when someone enters your site. Fun, fun, fun ;D

Comment: Clicky is free open source or paid one..

Comment: It's free, although you can pay for it to get more features kind of. But I don't. Not sure if it is open source or not since I haven't checked. Don't really care that much if it is open source or not :)

Answer (score -1):

If you are beginner, you can try this easy and simple but in JS code to get all stats from http://www.eaglestats.com/

Or if you want a very simple one without stats in PHP, try this : http://www.phpsimple.net/tutorials/real_visitor_counter/

Answer (score -1):

I have myself discarded Google Analytics, Piwik/Matomo and OWA - as they're all bloated overkills for my needs (but I self host many sites). I am preparing to write my own analytics, because Mint cannot be downloaded anymore.

If anyone knows of someone else who has started an interesting open source project focusing on minimalistic analytics, I'd sure like to know about it, as google search doesn't give many options.